# How to get the installer path in Inno Setup?

Tags: path, installation, inno-setup

Do you know the right method to get the installer path in Inno Setup?

I want to catch that value inside the `[Code]` section.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`{srcexe}` will give you the path and filename of the setup.
`{src}` will give you just the installer path.

Answer (score 20):

You should use the `{srcexe}` [constant](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm). In Pascal scripting, you can obtain the values of constants using the [`ExpandConstant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm) function, as in

```pascal
path := ExpandConstant('{srcexe}');
```

Comment: @ewlung: You should accept one of the answers by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.