# Get FileName of setup.exe File

Tags: inno-setup

how do i get the Exe-Name of the setup file itself?

I want to get the exe filename itself written to a variable in the inno setup script.

Inno Setup version 5.5.3

Comment: There is constant for it `{srcexe}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the installer path in InnoSetup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305815/how-to-get-the-installer-path-in-innosetup)

Answer (score 8):

You can extract your setup exe name from constant `{srcexe}` and write is as custom Variable String.

Example:

```
ExtractFileName(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'))
```

In Code:

```
   [Code]
    function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
    var
    SetupName : String;
    begin
      SetupName := ExtractFileName(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}')); 
        MsgBox(SetupName, mbInformation, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
    end;
```

> {srcexe}
>
> ```
> The full pathname of the Setup program file, e.g. "C:\SETUP.EXE".
> ```

More info about [Inno Setup's Constants](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts)